# Calling a function (ex. namespace.show) by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function with a namespace based on its name.

Perhaps some background: What I want is, dynamically bind pages via  **$.mobile.loadPage(inStrUrl, { showLoadMsg: false });** and then, based on the current page, invoke a function within a loaded page. For example: each page has a showFilter function, the Event is attached to a main.html - page which should call the matching function in the current page.

I also tried some solutions, with jquery too, but nothing works for me.

This is my function code:

```
function namespace() { }
namespace.showFilter = function () {
        alert("Test");
    }
```

And want to "invoke" or "call" it via its name. 
This is what i tried at least.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var fn = window["namespace.showFilter"];
fn();
});
```

I get error **TypeError: fn is not a function**

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xBCes/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it in the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window["namespace"]["showFilter"]();
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window["namespace"].showFilter();
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.namespace.showFilter();
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. [When I try it](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/R5RuJ/), I get the error "TypeError: window.namespace is undefined".

Comment: jslint prefers the last one :-)  Oh yeah and the `var fn = ` part is unnecessary in all examples.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Please learn the features of jsFiddle. You have the JavaScript set to execute `onLoad` (on the left-hand side of the screen), which doesn't create the function you declared as global

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to manually set it to window.

```
window.namespace = function() { }
window.namespace.showFilter = function () {
            alert("Test");
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var fn = window["namespace"]["showFilter"];
    fn();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xBCes/4/

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$(function() {
    window.namespace.showFilter();
});
```

P.S. I shortened the `$(document).ready(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
function namespace() {}
    namespace.showFilter = function () {
            alert("Test");
        }


$(document).ready(function() {
    var fn = namespace.showFilter();
    fn();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xBCes/3/